# Jenkins shell script stuck on git clone

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins

I am trying to nest a shell script into a Jenkins job but the script will infinitely get stuck when using the bash `git clone` command.

[image: jenkins job console output]

It doesn't even send me an error. I suspect the script is asking for a password when coming to the `git clone` command.

*Jenkins Job Configuration* :

```
#!/bin/sh
set -x
whoami #returns 'jenkins'
sudo -u root ./my_script.sh
```

*my_script.sh*

```
whoami #returns ROOT
sudo git clone 'https://myusername:mypassword@my.forge.fr/project/my-project.git' -b "master" --verbose
```

**What have I tried so far**

1. I edited my sudoers and added `jenkins ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL`
2. I intentionnaly wrote wrong credential in the `git clone` command, and I get an error `remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied`
3. With a terminal, I went in my workspace project, switched to `jenkins` user and ran `sudo ./my_script.sh` and it worked fine, **no password asked**.
4. It also work fine when ran under `root` user ( not a surprise )

Does anyone know how I can get my job to make this command pass ?

**Edit**

I am on Mac OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved it, it did come from a credential, but not the one I thought of. The problem came from **Keychain Access**. Also I appologize, I did not specified I was on **Mac**, I thought it wasn't relevant here since I was using bash.

When running the script under the Jenkins user, it worked fine as I was using sudo, but when I tried to run directly the `sudo git clone 'https://myusername:mypassword@my.forge.fr/project/my-project.git' -b "master" --verbose` I got an error :

[image: Keychain]

*I couldn't find the error message in english, but basically it says **"unable to find a Keychain to store..."** and the answers "cancel" and "reset my default keychain"*

From there I :

1. Created a new Keychain called `jenkins-dev` in the Keychain manager
2. I copied it from `/Users/myuser/Library/Keychains` to `/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Library/Keychains` under myuser
3. Then I ran `security unlock-keychain /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Library/Keychains/jenkins-dev.keychain-db` under jenkins user
4. finally `security default-keychain  /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Library/Keychains/jenkins-dev.keychain-db` under jenkins user
5. I ran once more the `git clone ...` command line under jenkins user, and then it found the keychain, stored the access and my Jenkins script wasn't stuck anymore

Hope this can help

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a key in ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub in that machine?

Comment: Yes I do, but only under `jenkins` user. when loged as `root` I don't even have that file. Is this normal?

Comment: (also just tried to run the script as `root` in the terminal, no password asked either)

Comment: I think Jenkins always need ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub present to run git commands, no matter what. Can you add it with user root? What happens if you run the script on Jenkins job with user jenkins instead of root?

Comment: If I launch the script directly with Jenkins user by command line it works fine. Also I don't know if it is related but today I tried to use the `jenkins git plugin` and now I get stuck on `git fetch` which runs until timeout.. My git is completely broken it seems...

Comment: If you are able to run on terminal with exact same scenario, it should not be a git problem. What happens if you run the script on Jenkins job with user jenkins instead of root?

Comment: In fact there are differences between a command line that is run under terminal with user jenkins and command line run in the job custom shell script (but I can't list them it's empirical). I finally found the solution, it came from the `Keychain`. A windows would pop up saying I do not have Keychain access for user jenkins (even though I run it with `sudo -u root`). I posted an answer above. Thank you for your help !

Comment: Thanks for sharing :) great that u figured it out!